# redirecting request to a different listener nginx

Tags: http, https, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am having two listener 80 and 777. Port 80 act as a reverse proxy. And port 777 does some extra stuff and want to redirect to port 80. How do I redirect to a different port in nginx? I was trying with rewrite but later figured out that it is only used for change of path

```
   ###
   server{
            listen  80;
            server_name     _;
            location / {
                    proxy_pass "http://upstream0;#" is included since links are not allowed in the post
            }

    }

    server{
            listen  777;
            server_name     _;
            #doing some other extra stuf
            //Want to redirect to port 80 under some condition
    }
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as far as nginx is concerned there's no real difference to passing something to another nginx listener/server and passing someting ot apache/mongrel/thin/... or any other http server
in other words if you want to pass things through to another listener you'd use proxy_pass

so what you want to do is something like

```
 location / {
   if (some condition) {
     proxy_pass http://$host:80
   }
 }
```

see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: proxy_pass is not allowed inside an if condition, you should use location / {
   proxy_pass http://$host:80;
}

Comment: according to the above linked documentation one of the allowed contexts for the proxy_pass directive is `if in location`, updated the example to make that explicit

Comment: this does not work either, it's not available in the documentation and I've tried it before.

Comment: what do you mean it's not availabe in the documentation? the relevant documentation bit is linked above! it has as allowed for the `proxy_pass` directive `context: location, if in location, limit_except`, note the second one. This has worked for me in the past, YMMV